# MYSQL - two tables in different databases

Tags: mysql, database, search

I need to check phone number to see if they match but the issue is, that one table is in database A and another is in database B.

I am wondering is there away to do a search like this:

```
update `chk_dup`, new set chk_dup.dup='Y' WHERE chk_dup.phone = new.phone;
```

But I guess I would need to do something like this:

```
update `A.chk_dup`, B.new set A.chk_dup.dup='Y' WHERE A.chk_dup.phone = B.new.phone;
```

I any one knows how to search two tables in completely different databases that would help.

Comment: Have you tried the second query?

Comment: yes but it did not work i am not sure if it phpmyadmin issue or my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your second one you had a syntax error, try this one:

```
UPDATE `A`.`chk_dup`, `B`.`new` 
SET `A`.`chk_dup`.`dup`='Y' 
WHERE `A`.`chk_dup`.`phone` = `B`.`new`.`phone`;
```